# In a metric space , if closure of every open set is open , then is every singleton open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M$  be a metric space such that the closure of every open set is open , then is it true that every subset of the space is open i.e. that the space is discrete ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Suppose $M$ is not discrete. Let $x$ be a non-isolated point, and let $x_1,x_2,\dots$ be a sequence of distinct points in $M\setminus\{x\}$ converging to $x.$ Construct pairwise disjoint open sets $U_n$ with $x_n\in U_n.$ The closure of the set $V=U_1\cup U_3\cup U_5\cup\cdots$ contains $x$ but it contains no neighborhood of $x,$ since it is disjoint from the open set $U_2\cup U_4\cup U_6\cup\cdots.$ Thus $V$ is an open set whose closure is not open.

Comment: how do you construct the $U_n$'s ?

Comment: One at a time. The first step is to construct an open neighborhood $U_1$ of $x_1$ whose closure contains none of the points $x_2,x_3,\dots.$ The next step is to construct an open neighborhood $U_2$ of $x_2,$ disjoint from $U_1,$ whose closure contains none of the points $x_3,x_4,\dots.$

Comment: how to get $U_1$ whose closure contains none of $x_2,x_3,...$

Comment: First, find a neighborhood $B$ of $x_1$ whose closure $\overline B$ does not contain $x.$ Since the sequence $x_2,x_3,\dots$ converges to $x,\ \overline B$ contains only finitely many terms of the sequence, say $x_2,\dots,x_n.$ Find a neighborhood of $x_1$ whose closure misses the points $x_2,\dots,x_n$ and intersect it with $B$ to get $U_1.$

Comment: Or we could quote a theorem which says that metric spaces are [collectionwise Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collectionwise_Hausdorff_space).